# What are some good pairs of transfer learning source and target datasets for image classification?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition, transfer-learning

As the title says, I'm curious about some well used transfer learning tasks.
ImageNet to other datasets is common, but what are something good pairs I can try and mess around with ?

Like CIFAR10 to MNIST, or CIFAR10 to CIFAR100, or CIFAR10 to SVHN.

While ImageNet is 224x224, and some of the above ones are 32x32, I also want to look at 64x64(like TinyImageNet)

As the title says, I'm curious about some well used transfer learning tasks.
ImageNet to other datasets is common, but what are something good pairs I can try and mess around with ?

Like CIFAR10 to MNIST, or CIFAR10 to CIFAR100, or CIFAR10 to SVHN.

While ImageNet is 224x224, and some of the above ones are 32x32, I also want to look at 64x64(like TinyImageNet)

P.S : I know that transfer learning is mainly used for situation where the target dataset is quite small, but I want to use some standard popular datasets and see how things work